# Jquery Ajax PHP File upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

Hi I am not able to get PHP FILES values in `view.php`, whereas normally it is found in `view.php`. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#uploadBtn').click(function() {
$.ajax( {
type: 'POST',
contentType:attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),
url: 'view.php',
data: $('myform').serialize() ,
success: function(data){
alert(data);
    }
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="view.php" name="myform">
<input id="f" type="file"  value=""  name="myfile"/>
<input type="button" value="try" id="uploadBtn" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the file path, can you post the exact Console error?

Comment: **Hi Chevi , thanks for your answer, No, path is ok , coz I have checked it with a normal ajax, it both file now residing at the same home**

Comment: Post the error you are getting, or anything really. With the code you have posted I doubt you will get much help

Comment: Here it is "ReferenceError: attr is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by trying to use "attr" as if it were a variable. You don't have to set the `enctype` of an AJAX request because that refers to forms only. You could set the appropriate `Content-type` though (to `"multipart/form-data"`)

---

Aside from that, you are trying to upload a file using AJAX, which is **not** *always* possible. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) for reference.

Quoting the accepted answer from that question:

> With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. E.g. through FormData object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old browsers.

I would recommend you try an AJAX file upload plugin, they usually do the job very well and will ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Bro, Btw, Do you recommend any specific plugin for that? which is easy to implement.

Comment: I don't have any recommendation, quick Google search will reveal lots of plugins for that matter.

Comment: Yea there is a lot but as per my requirement, itz better to create my own ,  plugins are not suites on my current code.

Comment: Well you could use XHR2 with a fallback for older browsers, but I would do a normal upload (without AJAX) and simulate that effect with an iframe. You can detect when the iframe loads (upload complete) in JS and react to that event.

Comment: OK thanks but I need full support on newer browser too. I slightly implemented the code , this time it is receiving the result but no FILES values yet.Says undefined index